# Не знаю как вывести текст из alert на html страницу. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Я хотел бы узнать как вывести текст на html страницу, который находится в alert (возможно я не правильно выражаюсь). В общем, вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function go(){

            var step = 0

            going: while(true){
                function getRandomInt(min,max){
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
                }

                var make_a_step = getRandomInt(1,7)

                if(make_a_step > 2){
                    step = step + 1
                    alert("Вы сделали шаг номер " + step + ".")
                } else {
                    alert("Вы не сделали шаг.")
                    break going
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Сделать шаг">
</body>
</html>
```

Я хотел бы, чтобы он выглядел так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно так я его представляю.
P.S. Сделал в фотошопе.

Если кто-то знает, как реализовать такое, то, пожалуйста, подскажите.
Если же такого на html и javascript сделать нельзя, то прошу сообщить об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно завести элемент, в который будем записывать вывод, пусть это будет span#result-field:

```
<span id="result-field"></span>
```

Далее его нужно позиционировать на странице так, чтобы при увеличении он рос вверх, добавим ему обертку, с фиксированной высотой, и расположим его внизу:

```
<div class="span-wrapper">
  <span id="result-field"></span>
</div>
```

И стили(вариантов исполнения много, я приведу пример с флексбоксом)

```
.span-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 }
```

Далее осталось записывать в спан результат по событию. Для этого используем свойство элемента `innerHTML`, а вешать на событие будет через `EventListener`

```js
var count = 0; //Создаем переменную

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var result = document.getElementById('result-field')
  result.innerHTML += 'test'+count+'<br>' // Достаем ее из замыкания
  count++
})
```

```css
.span-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  }
```

```html
<div class="span-wrapper">
  <span id="result-field"></span>
</div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я чертовски благодарен вам. Долго искал ответ, но не находил, а вы просто спасли меня. Ещё раз огромное спасибо!

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, как в этом коде сделать рандомное слово или цифру, а не одно слово?

Comment: Можете использовать замыкание, или вашу же функцию getRandomInt

Comment: Я пробую сделать со своей функцией, но пока у меня ничего не выходит.

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Очередной раз спасибо. Огромное спасибо!)